Bicolor/double-sided feathers as part of a thermoregulatory apparatus?
The project I'm working on right now has a much longer day than ours, which would result also then in higher thermal swings. Looking at earth and humans, depending on the solar radiation an area gets, the native inhabitants are more likely to have lighter or darker skin tones, in order to absorb harmful solar radiation. But if that radiation is blocked one way or another (i.e. by feathers or underlying skin melanin), I can see the opposite colour gradient occurring to maintain a good heat balance. When less sun is available, you'd want to compensate by absorbing more solar radiation; when more is available, you'd want to do the opposite.
My idea here being that a species has evolved with feathers that are, on one side, matte black, and on the other, a sort of shiny white. Basically maximizing the possible range of albedoes. In order to maintain a stabler temperature, these feathers are able to rotate to show one side or the other to the sun, thereby absorbing the desired amount of solar radiation - probably, this would entail a mixed array of black and white for the vast majority of the time.
This is a binary planetary system, as well, which means that the second planet will provide a reasonably large source of reflected light at night, allowing this mechanism to function to some degree during both daytime and nighttime.
My question is, would this be a reasonable thermoregulatory strategy? Keep in mind that it can absolutely be supplemented by heat exchange membranes, internal heat generation, etc... I only want to know if this could provide enough useful temperature management to actually develop in the first place.
A couple (edited) extra bits of info that seem potentially important:

These are flightless birdlike animals, living on a large island chain. They don't have any predators on land and don't ambush hunt.
Importantly, this is mediation between extremes of day and night temperatures. There are no seasons, just very long days and nights that get much hotter and colder. This is why actually altering or shedding feathers doesn't work.
Camouflage is not a concern
This can serve other purposes (i.e. mating display)
By "black" and "white", I do mean maximum absorption of light and minimum reflection of light, as far as is biologically realistic.
I've so far understood active thermoregulation to be much more energy intensive than passive, i.e. controlling the amount of energy you absorb rather than generating or dissipating it. Using less energy means less food use, so more can exist in an area with limited food reasources; this is part of why I wanted a passive thermoregulatory mechanism.


Animals which are able to maintain a stable body temperature are able to maintain a stable body temperature. Having a means to control the albedo of the integument may be of some small help to animals which are not able to maintain a stable body temperature. (And feathers are very very good thermal insulators, anyway.)

@AlexP, I agree- it's definitely very feasible for thermoregulation to occur in other ways. My observation being that, active thermoregulation can be energy intensive. Mammals have to eat more than reptiles for that reason. In an area (island chain) with less land and food resources, a larger population of these animals would likely benefit from more passive thermoregulation to reduce their energy needs and stress on their bodies. I'm mainly unsure as to how much of a benefit this particular method would provide, and/or if it would actually be able to fill the role of passive thermoregulation.

Rather than flip around the feathers, you can do a lot of other things, like: Turning most of the wing upside down, having the bird lie on its back, or hide the heat absorbing feathers below the other (through folding their wings up). That said, is there no shadow your birds could move to? Or water to cool of in? Or mud to cover themselves with?

I can't argue with @L.Dutch, there's no example of life on Earth using color-changing feathers (or skin, or scales, etc.) for temperature regulation. Darker human skin lowers the chance of skin cancer and slightly lowers the risk of burning, but it does nothing for thermal regulation.
But that doesn't mean your world can't have it. Let's answer the question from the perspective of the science-fiction tag.

Some birds change color through abrasion, meaning the tips of feathers are worn off, exposing a different color underneath. This method could be rationalized by your feathered creatures moving less often during one climatic period and moving a lot during another.

Some hummingbirds change color based on the position of the feather (giving credence to your idea of turning a feather over, although that's a pretty complicated action that's unlikely to evolve).

Most birds change color simply by molting (shedding feathers and growing new at the change of seasons).


Any of these could be used to rationalize the color change you're looking for and that thermally regulates their temperature because you declare it to be so in your world.
Be careful what you ask for: you tagged your question science-based
Once again supporting @L.Dutch's answer, it should be noted that the color of the feathers have almost nothing (possibly nothing at all) to do with thermal regulation. Feather density, down, and the ability to expand/constrict blood circulation in the skin would have much, much more to do with it.
Why? Because there is a great deal more light streaming down from a star than the visible spectrum, and color changing white-to-black would at best only affect visible spectrum light. It wouldn't affect the thermally efficient infrared spectrum or the usually-burns-your-skin ultraviolet spectrum (much less any of the other spectra). This is why you don't see color as a natural thermal regulation.
Besides, you might want to ask yourself why the Bedouin wore black robes and herded black goats in the desert. (Hint: it wasn't because they couldn't get white robes or white goats.)

We can generalize "black" to mean "absorbing most stellar flux", and "white" to "reflecting most stellar flux". It's really about emissivity, not color; I'll try to put together an answer, because that raises some other interesting issues.

@jeffB I don't believe so with the [tag:science-based] tag, but I look forward to your answer.

Bonus points for bringing up the Bedouin example!

A few notes here (great answer overall)... the problem with some of the colour changing methods you lay out here is that they wouldn't really work on the fast timescale. My world doesn't have seasons, but has high swings in temperature over the course of the day, which result from a significantly longer day/night cycle. That's why I considered this idea in the first place.
I think I did mention that I wanted to "maximize the possible range of albedoes"... which, as @jeffB mentioned, enclose a broader spectrum than just visible... that said perhaps my black/white wording was confusing.

@MaxBird While you might think that only leaves solution #2, you might be missing the point of the value of this site. You're assuming all three examples are the one and only way those three solutions can manifest. That's not worldbuilding. Those three solutions can all be used at whatever speed you want to use them because on your imaginary world they evolved that way. As for the issue of spectrum width... you tagged your question [tag:science-based]. Did you mean to tag it [tag:science-fiction]?

@JBH I'm just skeptical that it's sustainable for a species to shed or alter its feathers every single day... it makes more sense to me that a species would be evolving super high and low albedo pigments than for it to periodically become naked and then regrow all its feathers in ~3 days. I'm not sure I follow the science-based vs. science-fiction issue either. I want to know if my idea is realistic for thermoregulation, and it's pretty clear to me why I can't have rapid shedding. My biggest questions here regard how effective albedo management could be, and if high/low albedo is feasible.

Is there a reason it would be better written as a science-fiction tag? Considering I would like to adhere as closely to reality as possible.

@MaxBird Sustainable? Worldbuilding's stated purpose is to help people create imaginary worlds. If we stick to [tag:hard-science], then we're stuck with the fact that what you're looking for is, insofar as science knows, impossible. If you find one or more of the presented [tag:science-based] solutions unbelievable for your imaginary world, you might be right... but you might also be having trouble using your imagination. Frankly, I find a natural high/low albedo harder to believe because there's no example of such a thing in nature. (AKA, [tag:science-fiction].)

@JBH You make a good point about the lack of analogous things on earth. There are no known cases of animals changing colour to thermoregulate on earth... however I've done some searching and came up with at least one study that suggests there is a clear evolutionary link, largely offset by predation. Would be happy to link if you need.
In this case, there are clear benefits to lighter or darker colour which do not require light-absorption extremes... so I would simply stick to the maximum realistic values. I would consider feathers turning over to be more realistic than daily shedding.

I'd also like to point out that the parameters here are different, as I laid out above in an edit to the original post. Namely, camouflage and predation are not a concern, less energy intensive thermoregulation methods are preferable, and temperature variates on a daily basis. In that light I think it's a bit misleading to consider the very different conditions on earth to be the base template, without also considering timescale, which would require constant feather replacement. If we do look at the analogous part, feathers, well... feathers take up to 12 months to regrow. Way too long.

@MaxBird You can't use the [tag:science-based] tag and claim it's a bit misleading to consider the very different conditions on earth to be the base template. Either you're looking for a science-based answer (and Earth is the one and only reference for science-based) or you're not. I've asked a number of times if you meant to use the [tag:science-fiction] tag and at this point I believe you did and just don't want to change your post. ... (*Continued*)

... Please note that "as realistic as possible" isn't what we do here and the [tag:science-fiction], [tag:science-based] and [tag:hard-science] tags are not intended to force a more realistic answer. Oh, we'll try... but nothing about what you're asking is realistic in any sense of the word. I think you have a cool worldbuilding concept, but you're stuck on a conceit. If the birds in your world can't molt in a day or two (nothing wrong with that on your imaginary world), that's your choice because there's no science supporting feathers that turn over. ... (*Continued*)

... My point? If you don't like my answer, down vote it. Stop arguing that your insensible solution to a fictional problem is so much superior to my insensible solution to a fictional problem. (And for the record, providing your own answer and expecting more is prohibited in the [help/dont-ask]. You got a bye as a new user.)

Actually, I thought your answer made some good points, and upvoted it! I commented mainly because I thought you'd misunderstood the core problem I was trying to solve, but clearly my tag usage caused confusion (probably my bad). Is science-based basically only usable for earth analogous science? The tag is summarized rather briefly, including "plausible answers based on Real World science that are not necessarily constrained to the known limits of Real World science.." which I assumed included extrapolation of known principles to fit a reorganization of factors with known effects. Was I wrong?

In any case... my questions around realism focus mainly on whether it would work for thermoregulation. As it stands I'm quite fond of the idea and want to make it work... but apologies, I do think I got a bit defensive of it without explanation. That said, suggestions for alternatives were outside the scope of the question, and I think I stated that earlier. Could have done a better job of it, I suppose? But I did say " I want to know if my idea is realistic for thermoregulation, and it's pretty clear to me why I can't have rapid shedding." earlier. I hadn't really wanted to debate it.

If we look at our planet and at animals living in areas with extreme climates, like the polar areas or warm deserts, where thermoregulation is critical, we see that none of them has evolved such a feature.
Creatures switching from a dark to a white fur between seasons actually follow the opposite pattern: white fur in winter, brown fur in summer. They do so because their main concern is not thermoregulation but camouflage: a dark fur on a snowy background stands out, and there is not much point in saving few Joules of body heat when you have to spend as much if not even more to evade a predator.
On the other extreme, creatures living in hot deserts have to bear freezing temperatures at night and scorching hot ones during the day, and they again do so without changing color of their fur: they manage well with just a single tone.

In this case, camouflage isn't a huge concern. This particular species lives on a number of islands that don't really support big predators; they eat mostly plants and fish. I also think there is sort of a false analog here between Earth and this project's creatures, in that coat shedding is more energy/resource intensive, and is seasonal... whereas, this world has negligible seasonality and most variation is on a daily basis. Hence, thermoregulation has to be able to both heat and cool the animal in a space of a few days, and shedding isn't practical any more.

I'm going to take the devil's advocate position, just for a little balance. Just because it hasn't happened doesn't mean it couldn't.
Right now, feathers have a mechanism similar to how human hairs stand up when you get chilly. The official term is horripilation. Instead of goose bumps, the feathers fluff up and produce an extra layer of insulating air trapped within the feathers. This is actually fantastic insulation, and mammals do it, too.
What you're looking for is rotational horripilation. Basically the same mechanism, but while fluffing up, it also flips the feathers over. For this to work, you either need pinfeathers, like penguins are covered with, or you need some mechanism to keep them sorted so they all flip over in unison.
An alternative might be that the animal has alternating stripes, and the muscles pull one color up and the other color down such that the preferred color of feather covers the other. If you can't imagine this, let me know and I'll draw a picture. Given the control that octopuses have over their chromatophors, I don't see this as too far fetched.
I think this is possible for flightless birds, but the horizontal orientation of feathers is important for wings to work properly. Maybe it could work out that only the upper body of the animal changes color?

They are indeed flightless, it's basically a case of islands making things bigger. Like a bigger dodo. Bringing up the insulative properties of the feathers is actually really helpful too - I thought about it a little bit but, actually the idea that the muscle contractions that flip the feathers also changes the underlying insulative properties is a fantastic thought and lends some added credibility to the idea. I'm very fond of it (potentially as a means of communication and mating display as well), so I'm grateful for any ideas to help make this work.

Very interesting question. Now L. Dutch and JBH gave you why thermal regulation cannot be linked to color, however, I will try to give you a solution to what you need:
Thermal regulation can be helped with moving/reorienting feathers to improve or hinder air flow. You can have two colored feathers that will look one color when inflated (allowing air flow) and another color when tucked tightly like a blanket. If you use dark color for night and light color for day time, it can also help with camouflage a bit as darker colors blend better at low light conditions while bright blueish white could blend with day time sky.
